# solr 3: multivalued field omitTermFreqAndPositions is ignored

Tags: solr, multivalue

We have 20mil document solr index which contains multiValued fields of numbers.
 We have omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" , but looks like solr still calculating idf and tf for the field. Is there any other way except creating custom similarity to fix this issue? I just want be match no match

```
<field name="nume" type="plong"     indexed="true"  stored="false" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true"  />
```

Comment: What is the output of debugQuery for a query to the field?

Comment: 2.296167 = (MATCH) product of:
  6.8885 = (MATCH) sum of:
    6.8885 = (MATCH) weight(nume1:6 in 545761), product of:
      0.63025683 = queryWeight(nume1:6), product of:
        10.929671 = idf(docFreq=1305, maxDocs=26812940)
        0.057664756 = queryNorm
      10.929671 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(nume1:6 in 545761), product of:
        1.0 = tf(termFreq(nume1:6)=1)
        10.929671 = idf(docFreq=1305, maxDocs=26812940)
        1.0 = fieldNorm(field=nume, doc=545761)
  0.33333334 = coord(1/3)